# inno setup extract exe to run before installation

Tags: inno-setup

in my setup i need to check if a program is installed and if not i need to install it before my app installation.
I don't know how to extract needed files before [Files] section 
This is my code:

```
[Files]
Source: "..\PREREQUIREMENTS\DicomObjects\DicomObjectsSetup43.exe"; DestDir: "{src}\PreReq\DO\Setup\"; DestName: "DOSETUP.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "..\PREREQUIREMENTS\DicomObjects\License\DicomObjects.lic"; DestDir: "{src}\PreReq\DO\Lic\"; Flags: ignoreversion

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);

begin

  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    if not FileExists(ExpandConstant('"{pf}\Medical Connections\DicomObjects\DicomObjects.ocx"'))then if MsgBox ('installazione DO', mbInformation, mb_YesNo) = idYes then 
    begin
      Exec(ExpandConstant('{src}\PreReq\DO\Setup\DOSETUP.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
      Exec('cmd.exe','/c COPY "{src}\PreReq\DO\Lic\*.*" "{pf}\Medical Connections\DicomObjects\"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    end;
  end;
```

I also tried this code but not work

```
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;

begin
    if not FileExists(ExpandConstant('"{pf}\Medical Connections\DicomObjects\DicomObjects.ocx"'))then  
    begin
        ExtractTemporaryFile('DOSETUP.exe');
        Exec(ExpandConstant('{src}\PreReq\DO\Setup\DOSETUP.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
        Exec('cmd.exe','/c COPY "{src}\PreReq\DO\Lic\*.*" "{pf}\Medical Connections\DicomObjects\"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Use InitializeSetup to do things as the setup starts. See [Inno Setup = How to copy a file before Setup Start?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540439/62576) for an example of doing so. There's also `PrepareToInstall`, which is demonstrated in the examples provided with Inno Setup.

Comment: @KenWhite . Unfortunately inno setup examples don't help me tu find best way. I prefer to use `PrepareToInstall` but i can't extract needed files before installation.

Comment: solved extract problem with `ExtractTemporaryFile('DOSETUP.exe');` and then `Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\DOSETUP.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);`