# Bundle PHP7 with electron VCRUNTIME140.dll error

Tags: php, windows, dll, electron, electron-packager

I'm using for the first time the npm module electron-packager. I want to bundle inside my app the compiled version of php. I've downloaded it from the official website and I've placed it inside a folder of the app named `php`. I've tried then to build a windows version of the application and it will be builded successfully but the included php version will not be loaded. I've tied to start the .exe manually but it will always give me an error about a missing dll: `The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll` is missing. 
I've found some question here on SO where is explained why this error happen, and it's suggested to install VC14 to solve the issue. I'm testing the windows app generated on a virtual machine, Is there any way to include the VC14 setup inside the app and then when app start if this dependency is not installed, run the setup process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Inno Setup to make an executable that will install your electron app. Using this tool you can install any dependency you need to run the app. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537071/inno-setup-how-to-copy-a-file-before-setup-start) for more detailed info about or this question if you have an installer that want to run [After/Before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589309/inno-setup-install-other-installer-and-run-it-before-continuing-my-install) the setup is complete.

Comment: I will try!Thank you for the reply.